# Neo-Khuzdul in The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, languages, dwarves, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

I'm interested to know what all the Khuzdul (and languages other than the Common Speech) spoken in the third movie of *The Hobbit* means, as well as written out so the spelling is seen.

I'd like the answer to be written with the correct spelling, along with the definition.

**Update:** Elvish translations have already come out with detail, so I'm not sure why Khuzdul is not?

**The DVD and Blu-Rays are out, so subtitles/clips should be available to those with access. Also, there may be commentary in the special features that reveals a little more.**

Answer (score 5):

You're not going to get this yet.

When the DVD is released with subtitles, you'll be able to see the Khuzdul words and their spelling there, but whether or not you'll see a translation depends on whether or not the filmmakers provide one.

To clarify: **most of the Khuzdul used in these movies was NOT created by JRR Tolkien** and therefore we **cannot** provide an answer to this sourced from Tolkien's works.

The **only** Khuzdul that Tolkien created was a few place names and Gimli's warcry at the Hornburg.  Everything else used in the movies was a subsidiary invention, by the linguist David Salo, and which is called "Neo Khuzdul".

[David Salo's blog may be viewed here](http://midgardsmal.com/) and there is a [Neo Khuzdul glossary here](http://midgardsmal.com/neo-khuzdul-glossary/).

Comment: Thanks, and I understand most khuzdul is not from Tolkien. However, I still believe that individuals who have studied Neo Khuzdul would have analysed the khuzdul from watching the movie, as Elvish has already been translated. If people have translated Elvish, what's stopping the khuzdul translations?

Comment: @Jont - My understanding is that the Elvish used in the movies is (1) already extremely well-developed by Tolkien, and (2) already translated, or at least printed as-is, in the books.  The same doesn't apply to the Khuzdul used in the movies.  In other words, there is no secondary reference available.

Comment: So Khuzdul was translated by the filmmakers in Desolation of Smaug?

Comment: @Jont - no, it wasn't.  The point is: **most of the Khuzdul used in the movies was invented by David Salo, not by Tolkien**.  There is no reference in Tolkien for it, it doesn't exist, there's no translation for it, there's nothing.

Comment: Ok, so the Elvish translated was all made by Tolkien? And, if Khuzdul was not translated by the filmmakers, who translated the Khuzdul in Desolation of Smaug?

Comment: @Jont - you seem to be still misunderstanding.  The Khuzdul in the movies was **invented** by the filmmakers, not by Tolkien.  **There is no Tolkien text containing this Khuzdul**.  Nobody translated it because it doesn't exist in the texts; it was invented for the movies and doesn't exist outside of the movies.

Comment: I assure you I understand what you're saying; however, who translated the Khuzdul in Desolation of Smaug? You haven't answered that question yet. I appreciate your patience to discuss with me. :)

Comment: @Jont We do not know for sure, but most likely it was David Salo, since he is the creator of Neo-Khuzdûl. It was definitely at least someone who worked with him on the movie if it wasn't him personally.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the new comment! I posted an update because now the DVD and Blu-Ray is out, people said that we would likely be able to get some Neo-Khuzdul from it. Have we?

Answer (score 0):

Some lines in *The Battle of the Five Armies* are:

Extended - Dain walkes with his army down the hillside. He says "Hey, Thorin! Ironfoot has come!" In the background you can hear a dwarf shout "Idmi d'dum!" (Welcome to the hall!"

Extended - Dain runs up to his army and says "You think I give a dead dog for your threats you pointy-eared princess. You hear that lads, lets give these bastards a good hammering!" A dwarf shouts "Yanâd Durinul!" (Sons of Durin!)

Normal - Dain turns to his army and says "Lets give these bastards a good hammering! A dwarf shouts "Yanâd Durinul!" (Sons of Durin!)

Normal - The elves get into formation. Dain shouts "Ihgirî ni-hun. Ifridî!" ( (Go) right into them. Make ready!)

If you want to learn more, go to [this blog about Tolkien languages](https://midgardsmal.com/) or look up [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxSucM4-5ac).

Comment: Hi there! People might want to learn more, but shouldn't have to jump too much between sites (plus, links rot); hence, if this blog or some "YouTube videos" contain more relevant information that you could [edit] into your answer, please do! This will make for a better answer. Gather all the relevant info in one place, etc, etc. May I also interest you in taking the [tour] and browsing the [help] to see how things work on this site?