# What are the dwarves saying (cheering or yelling) after Dain´s words: Let's give those bustards a good hammering?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, dwarves, the-battle-of-the-five-armies

I was wondering what are the words that the dwarves are yelling before battle in the movie *The Battle of Five Armies*. Can anyone tell me what those words are?

Comment: http://midgardsmal.com/questions-and-answers/

Comment: Dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80115/neo-khuzdul-in-the-hobbit-the-battle-of-the-five-armies [Closed]

Comment: You can hear it a little more clearly in this clip: https://youtu.be/3DD3aSIbT6M?t=12

Answer (score 1):

### "Yanâd Durinul" - Sons of Durin

> from David Salo's [YND] birth/son; as in "ênâd" (birth) - Ereb. Khuzdul: "Yand" (son), "Yanâd" (sons).
>
> From this video, see 0.19;
>
> > <sub>Youtube user: The Dwarrow Scholar</sub>

**It's a battlecry**, similar to the one Gimli says:

> 'Baruk Khazad! Khazad ai-menu!'
>
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers* - Book III, Chapter VII, Helm's Deep</sub>

Comment: I would just like to add that this is "Neo-Khuzdul" and therefore completely non-canon.